# Move tags to below title instead of at end of question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Ever had this feeling that you're missing some information when you're reading through a question?

Well I do too. You start reading this really long question only to find out that some specific information is only provided as a tag.

Wouldn't it be friendlier (as in usability) if the tags were placed just beneath the title and above the question's body?

Comment: It's actually like that on mobile and I like it better, so I would vote for a yes

Comment: Perhaps in both places - at least if the question is longer than X lines?

Comment: While you can sometimes see a tag in the tab/window title in the browser, it may not always be the one you need to see. I would also vote yes to having them at the top (or top and bottom for longer posts).

Comment: Well there seems to be a user script as per [Arulkumar's answer](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2772/15356), but is this the solution, seeing as I was expecting a feature-request?

Answer (score 3):

I have created an [User script](https://stackapps.com/q/7445) for this request.

This script helps you to clone the tags and place below the title. Also this will clone the tags if the tag's position is greater than the initial window size.